# Connect Mac to raspi4(kali) via direct ssh

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, mac, kali-linux

Is there a way to connect to a Raspberry Pi 4 with kali linux ARM via Direct SSH, without any other network or router set up?

I have set up a little raspi4 with kali linux (latest version atm.). I created a network on the Mac and I am trying to connect the Pi to the network to then ssh into it. The problem is that i cannot connect the Pi to the mac network via ethernet, only by wifi and that is kind of a setback because i planned to use the wifi from the Pi to connect to other networks where i can't use a cable...

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from plugging in an extra wifi adapter to one of its usb port...

Comment: So you want your Pi to connect to 2 different wifi networks at the same time, right? If yes then there's no other choice than using an extra wifi adapter, as suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: Can it use 3 networks at once? for example one by ethernet, one by it's built in network card and one by a wifi dongle?

Comment: Why not? Or is there any special implication from you with `at once`? (Though unless you set it up with bond or whatsoever, if possible at all, don't expect things like "increased speed due to combined throughput". To make things simple you might even you want configure `default` route on only one of three. Here we/I are/am merely talking about like using multiple interfaces for multiple LANs.)

Comment: Note that in my experience Pi can be very delicate when it comes to (electrical) power. Some WiFi dongle can be very consuming and hence make things unstable especially if you are using an SSD via USB that is solely powered by the port.